# Flutter ListView.separated frame drop when loading huge list

Tags: smooth-scrolling, flutter-listview, flutter-desktop, lazylist

I'm trying to display a **lazy list** in **flutter for windows**. The list has **approximately 2300 elements** in it. The list is within a FutureBuilder, whose future is to fetch the 2300 elements from Hive database. Each **element in the list is a MaterialButton** with some properties. Im not getting smooth scrolling when scrolled fast. Some **frames are being dropped**. I have tried **cacheextend** and setting **automatickeepalives to true.** Still having the same problem. When **ItemExtend** is set to a large number(say 40), the scrollView **works fine** without frame drop. In release mode, it has better performance, but still some frames are being dropped. What is the best solution available to this problem?

```dart
//this Rawscrollbar is returned if the future is have some data
RawScrollbar(
                    isAlwaysShown: true,
                    controller: scrollControllerMLC,
                    thickness: context.percentWidth * .8,
                    radius: Radius.zero,
                    thumbColor:
                        SearchLeftContainerColors.headPoolListThumbColor,
                    child: ListView.separated(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                          context.percentWidth * .5,
                          context.percentHeight * 0,
                          context.percentWidth * 1,
                          context.percentHeight * 1),
                      itemCount: lengthOfBoxes,
                      controller: scrollControllerMLC,
                      // addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
                      // physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                        return ListButtonMEDLC(data[index], index);
                      },
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Divider(
                          color: SearchLeftContainerColors
                              .headsPoolSeparatorColour,
                          height: 1,
                        );
                      },
                    ));




class ListButtonMEDLC extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final int index;
  ListButtonMEDLC(this.text, this.index);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      color:
          (context.watch<ListButtonColorChangerMEDLC>().isSelectedList[index])
              ? SearchLeftContainerColors.headPoolListSelectedColor
              : SearchLeftContainerColors.headPoolListColor,
      hoverColor:
          (context.watch<ListButtonColorChangerMEDLC>().isSelectedList[index])
              ? SearchLeftContainerColors.headPoolListSelectedColor
              : SearchLeftContainerColors.headPoolListHoverColor,
      highlightColor: SearchLeftContainerColors.headPoolListHighLightedColor,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: context.percentWidth * 1.1,
              color: (context
                      .watch<ListButtonColorChangerMEDLC>()
                      .isSelectedList[index])
                  ? Colors.white
                  : Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        context.read<ListButtonColorChangerMEDLC>().changeIsSelectedList(index);
      },
    );
  }
}

//this it the future of the future builder;
loadDrugBox() async {
  Map boxes = await DB.boxes.getBoxAsMap("drugs");
  lengthOfBoxes = boxes.length;
  return boxes;
}

//Provider
class ListButtonColorChangerMEDLC extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<bool> isSelectedList = List.generate(lengthOfBoxes, (index) => false);

  changeIsSelectedList(int indexOfSelected) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfBoxes; i++) {
      if (i == indexOfSelected) {
        isSelectedList[i] = true;
      } else
        isSelectedList[i] = false;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[image: Here is the GIF of the issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I solved this issue by replacing material button which was an expensive widget with gestureDetector.